# regex or something to find a file in php

Tags: php, regex, file

I have a name in a database, lets say its "DFectuoso" and some legacy system stored DFectuoso_randomnameofafile.doc.

Now I want to find all the filed "DFectuoso" owns and display links to them in a PHP page.

What would be the way to start on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try with [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) in combination with [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile).

Off the top of my head:

```
$findname = 'DFectuoso';
foreach (glob('/path/to/somewhere/'.$findname.'*') as $file) {
  provide_a_link_to($file);
}
```

and just pass the file with `readfile()`.

Remember, if you are using `$_GET` to pass the chosen file to the user, sanitize and validate the permissions first. Don't do just `readfile($_GET['chosenFile']);` or you'll get in trouble!

Comment: My first thought was an exec() call to 'find'.  Your way is much better.

Answer (score 2):

A good way is using [glob()](http://php.net/glob).

```
$files = glob("PATH_TO_FILES/DFectuoso_*.doc");
echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($files as $f)
    echo '<li><a href="'.$f.'">'.$f."</a></li>\n";
echo "</ul>\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

In case it's not as simple as finding files with a certain prefix, you can do something like this:

```
$files = glob('*');

function filter_files($filename) {
    // Do any processing you want on the filename here
    $file_matches = preg_match('/^DFectuoso.*\.(doc|txt)$/', $filename);
    return $file_matches;
}

$found_files = array_filter($files, 'filter_files');
```